# How to remove \n\t\r from list in Python?

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

Code :

```
list = ["\r\n                    Opportunities\r\n                ", "\r\n                    Careers\r\n                ", "\r\n                    Education & training\r\n                ", "\r\n                Find Your Future\r\n ","\r\n\tSanderson        Recruitment, Solutions, Executive, Consulting\r\n"]
```

Output I want:

```
["Opportunities","Careers","Education & training","Find Your Future","Sanderson Recruitment, Solutions, Executive, Consulting"]
```

Since it is a list

Comment: Where did this list come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to strip whitespace from your strings. You can apply the `strip` method to every element of your list using a list comprehension.

```
mylist = ["\r\n                    Opportunities\r\n                ",
    "\r\n                    Careers\r\n                ",
    "\r\n                    Education & training\r\n                ",
    "\r\n                Find Your Future\r\n ",
    "\r\n\tSanderson        Recruitment, Solutions, Executive, Consulting\r\n"
]

newlist = [s.strip() for s in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip surrounding whitespace from strings

```
out = [x.strip() for x in l]
```